# Cronjob to run every 30 minutes

Tags: shell, time, cron

I want to set a cronjob entry that runs a script every 30 minutes from 9:00 to 18:00 but I do not want it to run at 18:30. The script should run for the first time at 9:00 and for the last time at 18:00. Is this possible?

Comment: Might be a better one for [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [unix/linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hmm, right.. I'll ask it there.

Comment: @user1405441 In the future, [don't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  Instead, ask a moderator to migrate your question or delete the original and repost yourself.

Comment: Alright @jw013, I'll not do that again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible; `cron` itself can't solve the task, but it is possible using additional shell command:

```
*/30 9-18 * * * root [ $(date +%H%M) = 1830 ] || your_command
```

`your_command` will be executed if and only if the current time is not equal to 18:30

Answer (score 3):

You might need to have two entries:

```
0,30 9-17 * * * /script
0 18 * * * /script
```

Alternatively, you could modify your script to check if it's close to 18:30 or not, and exit early if so.